# Position div depending on distance browser edge (javascript)

Tags: javascript, positioning, tooltip

I am trying to create a small tooltip script that mostly relies on css. The bit of JavaScript I can't figure out is how to position the div based on its distance to the browsers edge.

When the div appears I would like it to check how close it is to the top, bottom, left and right. For example if there is not enough space to display the div above the tooltip link it should position it below the link.

Essentially I would like the div to be "aware" of its position and know where to go to make sure it is visible.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I just had to write very similar code myself, for use with [tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/) (so my solution uses jQuery). Here's the basic math, assuming `<div id="mydiv">...</div>` is the div you're working with. I account for the div's height and width when measuring the distances to the right and bottom edges as well.

`dTop`, `dBottom`, `dLeft`, and `dRight` are the distance from the div's top, bottom, left, and right edges, respectively, to the same edge of the viewport. If you want to measure based on the upper-left corner of the div, don't subtract `dTop` or `dLeft` when computing `dBottom` and `dRight`.

```
var $doc = $(document),
    $win = $(window),
    $this = $('#mydiv'),
    offset = $this.offset(),
    dTop = offset.top - $doc.scrollTop(),
    dBottom = $win.height() - dTop - $this.height(),
    dLeft = offset.left - $doc.scrollLeft(),
    dRight = $win.width() - dLeft - $this.width();
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Measuring Element Dimension and Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530302.aspx) for help

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks Matt Ball - in my defence, the meta discussion you link hadn't taken place when I'd posted my original answer!

Answer (score 0):

This [cheat sheet](http://attic.scripteka.com/prototype_cheatsheet_1.6.0.2.pdf) for the [Prototype library](http://prototypejs.org) has a good example.